# Docker for mac - can't curl my container

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

Running docker for Mac 17.06.0 I have created a docker file that creates an image of Apache server. Notice it exposes port 80.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
ADD index.html /var/www/html/
CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
EXPOSE 80
```

In the same folder of the Dockerfile I have created a simple index.httml file.
Then I built and ran it using

```
docker build -t webserver .
docker run -d webserver
```

I took the IP address of the running container using

```
docker inspect [container_name] | grep -i IPAddress
```

and when I curl

```
curl 172.17.0.2
```

I get no answer.

I do get an answer when running -p 80:80 and using localhost in the curl command.

```
 curl localhost
```

But I want to understand why can't I curl the container IP.

Questions:

1. How can I get an answer for my curl?
2. I understand I can't ping my container when using docker for Mac ([link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers)).
   Can I telnet it just to verify that the port is exposed?
3. Can I SSH it?

Answer (score 3):

On Docker for Mac the Docker engine is running inside a small VM using Hyper-V. As consequence, the ip `172.17.0.2` is valid only inside that VM and not on your host system. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#the-docker-for-mac-environment for more details and comparison to other VM concepts like Docker Machine.

Comment: So how can the OP get an answer for that curl?

Answer (score 0):

When you run your Docker container, you need to bind a local port to the container like so:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 webserver
```

where the first `80` is the port on the localhost and the second is the port on the container that is exposed. Just having the port exposed in the `dockerfile` is not enough to access it from the localhost.

Comment: Thanks. This solution just forwards my 'curl localhost' request to the container. My question is about running with the container IP - 'curl 172.17.0.2'